# AngularJS: ng-repeat to assign different values to buttons; how to extract the value to js when pressed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, button, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using angular to build a waitinglist-system, where you first join a waitinglist, and then can be moved to the memberlist. I use `ng-repeat` to fill inn the table with the rows of waiting people, and I assign a button to each row, which can be pressed to move that particular person to the memberlist.

**First problem:**
I am not sure if i assign the value to the button in the correct way. It is supposed to be the email of the person.

```
<input type="submit" ng-click="makeMember()" ng-model="member" value="Member" id="{{person.email}}">
```

**Second problem:**
I want to use this users email in order to make a sql query to send to the database to move the person to the memberlist (email is primary key).

I am trying to use `$scope.member` to reference the `ng-model`, but that only gives me an undefined value.

The `makeMember` function is just to see if it works (which it doesnt).

```
$scope.makeMember = function() {
    alert("Person email: " + $scope.member);
};
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `member` in like this: `ng-click=makeMember(member)`.

```
$scope.makeMember = function(member) {
    alert("Person email: " + member);
};
```

**[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/aGAlaba/1/edit)**

The issue you are having is that `$scope` refers to the controller's `scope`, not the child scope created by `ng-repeat`. The only way `$scope.member` would work is if you had defined it in the controller.

Comment: Wow, that was quick, and it works! Thank you very much!